# problems with flags intent

Tags: android, task

On my code I have 2 apps.
the app a that starts app b, like a launcher.

the code app a looks like that:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.test.vayo");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

the code on app B:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, first.class);
            intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

my problem that to start task b only if a didnt start the app b.For that I am trying to bring to front the task that already running and not to start all activities from the root one, just to bring to front back stack of the privous task.
for that I am using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT its works only if I run first app b and the app a, but if I run a and then run b it isnt working,its starts b from the root activity.

Comment: I really didn't understand who is launching who and what you want to do. If you could explain it in a more clear English, I would be happy to help.

Comment: ok the flow is app a starts app b, or the user can starts app b directly. I want that if b is started already and some one is starting the b in other way I want to bring to the front the task that already running, hope that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did  it with  flags one flag on the app a and the other one on the app b, the flag

```
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, for launcher activity of B, declare

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

You do not need to do anything in B.

Comment: and when I will try to launch it from other it will bring to the front the task that already running?

Comment: Yes. Try and see. If not working, we can try finding another solution.

Comment: sorry it isnt working I added this to my splash activity on app b still the same problem

Comment: You said either A launches B or you can directly launch B. You didn't mention that you launch anything from B.

Comment: task b have activities and splash screen, app b starts from splash screen. can see the code from splash screen that its starts first.class , this code on my main post

Comment: You didn't mention that in the original question. You can wait for someone else to help you. Good luck!